# how to draw line in jlayeredpane Java

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, line, graphics2d, jlayeredpane

I want to draw line in my jLayeredPane
and this is my project from netbeans.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6e6jjVl5-sCMkJFcEI3MkZEZ1E/view

I have problem when i clicked my button why i can't draw line in my jlayeredpane??where's my wrong with this code?

I want to draw some line in my jlayeredpane when click button draw.I try to add jlayerpane1.add some component.and i set this for visible.

how to fix it?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLayeredPane1.add(new JComponent(){                                   
     ArrayList<Shape> linesList = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    private Shape line = null;
    {
    MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter(){
                @Override
        public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e){                       
        line = new Line2D.Double(e.getPoint(), e.getPoint());
        linesList.add(line);
        repaint();
        }
                @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        Line2D shape =(Line2D)line;
        shape.setLine(shape.getP1(), e.getPoint());
        repaint();
        }
                @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        line = null;
        repaint();
        }
    };
    addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
    addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
    }
        @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for(Shape content : linesList){
        g2d.draw(content);
    }
  }          
    });
    jLayeredPane1.setVisible(true); // set for visible
}
```

Comment: If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem because we don't know the context of how you create the frame, layered pane and custom painting panel so we can't tell if code is correct or not since we are not mind readers.

Comment: thx @camickr im using Netbean IDE i just call that button.and add jlayeredpane1...i've been set my resolurion program 1024x768

Comment: Don't understand the point of your last comment. You've been given an answer. If the answer doesn't help then post a `SSCCE`. A comment doesn't help.

Comment: `i've been share my source code` - post the code on the forum, not on google drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JLayeredPane` uses a null layout. So when you add your custom painting panel to the layered pane you need to give the panel a size otherwise the size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

So the code should be something like:

```
JPanel panel = new CustomPaintingPanel();
panel.setSize(300, 300);
layeredPane.add(panel, ...);
frame.add(layeredPane);
```

Comment: sorry im not using JPanel.Im so sorry..im using jlayeredPane.and i've been share my source code..for SSCCE @_@b..

Comment: `im using jlayeredPane.` - don't paint on a JLayeredPane. You paint on the component you add to the layered pane as I demonstrated above.